# Terraform Dynamic Block to convert external variable into a Map

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to convert the data from external variable into a Map which i need to pass to a Module

We have an Module for AWS ALB and it is defined as below:

```
module "alb" {
    source = "github_url"
    name   = var.name
    listeners = {
       listener = {
         port = 443
         protocol = "HTTPS"
         certificate_arns = [""]
         target_group_name ="test_tg"  
       }
    }

    target_groups = {
       test_tg = {
          port   = var.port
          target_type = "ip"
       }
    }
  }
  ...
```

}
How ever i don't want to hard code the target groups. And i am planning to pass them as external variables.

How ever when i try to build the target_groups using Dynamic block I cannot provide the key value at run time.

Here is how my external variable is defined as

```
clusters = [{"name":"cluster1", "ip_address":"10.10.10.10","port":"8080"},{"name":"cluster2", "ip_address":"10.10.10.11","port":"8080"}]
```

And I changed the terraform template as below:

```
module "alb" {
        source = "github_url"
        name   = var.name
        listeners = {
           listener = {
             port = 443
             protocol = "HTTPS"
             certificate_arns = [""]
             target_group_name =var.clusters[0].name  
           }
        }
    
        dynamic "target_groups" {
           for_each = { for cluster in var.clusters: cluster.name => cluster}
           content {
               each.value.name = {
                   port        = each.value.port
                   target_type = each.value.ip_address
               }
           }
        }
      }
      ...
   }
```

I am getting the Error Argument or Block definition is required on line where I have each.value.name = {}

I tried defining this map in locals and pass that to target_groups with no luck.

Even if i change my clusters variable to a map instead of a list i.e,

```
clusters = {"cluster1":{"ip_address":"10.10.10.10","port":"8080"},"cluster2":{ "ip_address":"10.10.10.11","port":"8080"}}
```

And change the code

```
module "alb" {
            source = "github_url"
            name   = var.name
            listeners = {
               listener = {
                 port = 443
                 protocol = "HTTPS"
                 certificate_arns = [""]
                 target_group_name =var.clusters[0].name  
               }
            }
        
            dynamic "target_groups" {
               for_each = var.clusters
               content {
                   each.key = each.value
               }
            }
          }
          ...
       }
```

It still complains that i cannot use "each.key" as key it needs to be hardcoded !! Why can't it be decided at run time ?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 1):

In your case `target_groups` is just a map, not a block. So you have to assign a map to `target_groups`, not a block:

```
module "alb" {
    source = "github_url"
    name   = var.name
    listeners = {
        listener = {
            port = 443
            protocol = "HTTPS"
            certificate_arns = [""]
            target_group_name =var.clusters[0].name  
        }
    }

    target_groups = { for cluster in var.clusters: 
                        cluster.name => {
                            port        = cluster.port
                            target_type = cluster.ip_address                    
                    }
                }
    

    
          }
          ...
       }
```